# How to iterate a VLOOKUP over multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have the following data

Column A  |  Column B  | M
Apple     |  Apple     |
Orange    |  Orange    |
Pear      |  Banana    |
Apple     |  Apple     |
Orange    |  Orange    |
Pear      |  Banana    |
Apple     |  Apple     |
Orange    |  Orange    |
Pear      |  Banana    |
Apple     |  Apple     |
Orange    |  Orange    |
Pear      |  Banana    |
Apple     |  Apple     |
Orange    |  Orange    |
Pear      |  Banana    |
Apple     |  Apple     |
Orange    |  Orange    |
Pear      |  Banana    |
Apple     |  Apple     |
Orange    |  Orange    |
Pear      |  Banana    |
Apple     |  Apple     |
Orange    |  Orange    |
Pear      |  Banana    |

Now I want to do a VLOOKUP on each of the data rows.. How do I do this?

This code works for one cell:

```
#working for one row
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'flat_user_data.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws["M10"] = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A10,'Emergency User Exclusions'!A:A,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)"
wb.save('flat_user_data.xlsx')
```

I've tried the following for multiple cells:

```
#multiple rows
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'flat_user_data.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
for i in ws.iter_rows():
    ws["M{i}"] = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A{i},'Emergency User Exclusions'!A:A,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)"
    wb.save('flat_user_data.xlsx')
```

However getting the following error
ValueError: M{i} is not a valid coordinate or range

Comment: `ws.iter_rows()` does not return row numbers, but tuples containing cell objects. You'll need to use another counter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put an 'f' in front of your string if you want to use variables between curly brackets.

Try the code below:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'flat_user_data.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
for i in ws.iter_rows():
    ws[f"M{i}"] = f"=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A{i},'Emergency User Exclusions'!A:A,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)"
    wb.save('flat_user_data.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks leonardo, Do you know how to skip the first 8 rows?

Comment: getting the following error

Comment: ValueError: M(<Cell 'GRC User Data Clean Up'.A15>, <Cell 'GRC User Data Clean Up'.B15>, <Cell 'GRC User Data Clean Up'.C15>, <Cell 'GRC User Data Clean Up'.D15>,